# How to remove the description( Powered by .....) of website from google search results

Tags: wordpress, web, code-search-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3NMG.jpg)

I have tried to rectify this by searching the powered by ... in my root directory but im unable to find it. please help me on this.

Comment: Those are your meta descriptions (if you have them) or content on the page if you don't have a meta description.  Probably the simplest way for you to do this is to install [SEO By Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) and configure your meta descriptions.

Comment: i have tried it earlier but not working..

Answer (score 1):

These are your meta descriptions as shown by Google on search results.

You have three things going on:

1. You are not waiting for Google to pick up your changes.  If you Google the name of your site, you will see that MANY of the changes to your meta descriptions are picked up.
2. The ones you have indicated in your screenshot are tag archives.  You have to specifically set those up.  In SEO by Yoast, you do it by: Log into your dashboard, go to "SEO" then "Titles & Meta", then click the "Taxonomies" tab, find the "Tags" section, and set the meta descriptions there.
3. Your site has likely been hacked.  See those links for anime? And see this screenshot (Google your domain "wadeguh.com" and see what comes up):
   [image: Google Search Results for WadeGuh.com]

How to fix this?
1. Clean up your hack.
2. Set up the Tag meta descriptions in Yoast.
3. Wait for Google to crawl again.